# How do I test an untrusted GUI application?

Tags: x11, virtual-machine, gui, testing

Not all applications we run come from trusted repos. Sometimes we get a package `.deb`, `.rpm`, `.tar`, etc. that contains an application we do not trust completely trust. I'm talking slight distrust, not full-flown paranoia.

Without going into a big debate about whether to run them or not, how would I go about running an untrusted GUI application with the basic criteria being:

- it does not have access to my important files
- isn't able to listen to keyboard or mouse input when it's not focused

## Possibilities I know of

### another, restricted user on another or the same system

The problem I have here is X. Sure you can run `xhost +local:restricteduser` or maybe `gksudo -u restricter thatapplication`, but would they fullfill the basic criteria listed above? Is it secure?
I doesn't seem so as I tested this with JDownloader, which ran in a VM I sshed into with X access and it had access to my clipboard...

### other machine/system (could be virtual)

This seems pretty safe as they could trash that other system and yours would still be ok, but spinning up a VM every time you the application seems like overkill (you must really, really distrust the application).

### other

I heard of an operation system under development that IIRC would create a new virtual machine per user. Can't remember the name...

Comment: https://firejail.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the threat model is focused on files and X access, files should be handled by creating a new user/group, and making sure file permissions are restrictive enough this user/group cannot access anything important.

Restrictions to X can be handled by starting a virtual X server (e.g. `vnc4server`) where you can control (e.g. via `xvnc4viewer`) that this server only sees mouse or keyboard activity when you explicitely focus the viewer window etc.

Of course nothing keeps you from using read-make *sandboxes* like `firejail` or others.